# FILTER by two condition then SUM the results

Tags: google-sheets

I not sure if I understand how FILTER is working.
I would like to `SUM` only the results that satisfy both conditions in the `FILTER` and get `8+10=18`, but it seems I'm getting `8+9+10=27` as if the first condition is ignored.

Both `=SUM(FILTER(E1:E10,MATCH(D1:D10, G1:G4), E1:E10 > 7))` and `=SUM(FILTER(E1:E10,MATCH(D1:D10, G1:G4) * (E1:E10 > 7)))` return `27`

Have any ideas?

Here is an [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S9wjWC2QcLc5cScLw_D26NP3vhIl5iKYYkyYyYIPNSE/edit#gid=1562703554) and a screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crucial thing is putting the third argument into the Match function to specify an exact match

```
=SUM(FILTER(E1:E10,MATCH(D1:D10, G1:G4,0), E1:E10 > 7))
```

Otherwise you get the position of the largest value less than or equal to the lookup value: e.g. for "G" you would get a match with "D" which would return 4. So the Match function in your original formula always returns a number >=1 which is treated as True.

It's interesting that the above formula works actually because a non-match will return #N/A but apparently it's treated as false - I don't know if this is documented.

I would always put

```
=SUM(FILTER(E1:E10,isnumber(MATCH(D1:D10, G1:G4,0)), E1:E10 > 7))
```

to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks @Tom, I've completely missed the fact that MATCH was in fact selecting everything